# Artscroll translation of Maharal's Be'er Hagolah

Tags: artscroll, maharal

Does anyone know if the [Artscroll translation of Maharal's Be'er Hagolah](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578194636.html) is an unabridged one of the entire sefer by the Maharal?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 3):

It is not an unabridged translation. As the author writes in the introduction

> Maharal's style is individualistic and difficult to penetrate. He
> uses terms and phraseology that can be seen in so many different ways,
> that the student may be left frustratingly in the dark. The answer is
> close at hand, but eludes firm clutching. Sometimes it helps to
> compare parallel texts in which the Maharal uses the same phrase or
> argument. My own experience, though, is that finding three similar
> texts, leaves me triply irresolute.
>
> There are no classic line-by-line commentaries to Maharal that have
> become popular. **I therefore attempted to storm the palace, and offer
> something other than a translation. In fact, I don't translate at all.
> I try to digest the Maharal's step-by-step development, and offer some
> understanding of what it may mean to us.**
>
> I have tried to steer a middle path between translation without
> comment, and complete modification and adaptation. These are not
> esays-based-upon. I have tried to remain faithful to the Maharal's
> own development of a topic. This means that more remains unsaid than
> stated, and this work is meant to be studied, not read. I've attempted wherever possible to convey the sense of each paragraph and argument,
> usually in the same basic order as the author. I have not held back in
> offering my own grasp of what he was getting at, but I have swallowed
> my words many times, and suppressed the desire to say much, much more.
> To do more would be imposing my own views more than tolerably.
>
> **I have not included every piece. I chose selections that I thought had the most interest to, and the most to contribute to, the
> contemporary student.** Maharal at times maps out an approach to
> unlock a difficult passage of Chazal, He will next apply the same
> approach to similar passages, which he sees as variations on the same
> theme.
>
> [...]
>
> **Omitted entirely are** the sections in the sixth Beer that attempt to
> harmonize the astronomy and cosmology of Chazal with that of
> sixteenth-century Europe. While these sections are of immense interest
> to scholars of the period, I have not yet discovered how these
> passages would help today's student harmonize Chazal with today's
> science. [...]